# Why are the Recent log messages not shown within admin/reports?

Tags: log-messages

The usual log reporting option "Recent log messages" is not showing up under 'admin/reports' (in the admin menu).

Any idea what might be causing that? Is there a module that provides this functionality?

Comment: check `View site reports` under permissions

Comment: I am logged in as admin, so should be able to see it. In permissions it is showing but not checked for anon user or authenticated user.

Comment: also check if the Database Logging module in Core - Optional is enabled.

Answer (score 7):

The "Recent log messages" is one of the submenu options located within admin/reports/dblog.

It becomes available after the core module `dblog` (Database Logging) is enabled.

If that core module is enabled, and it still isn't showing up, then it is probably because permission "`View site reports`" (within "System") has not been granted to the user trying to access that report.

Comment: For future visitors still using drupal 7: Disabling and enabling the dblog module for some reason might also fix it.